# How to get class value from section wrapper with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape some data from a car dealers website. This is the random car i am currently trying to get data about: https://www.bilbasen.dk/brugt/bil/audi/a4/20-tfsi-190-sport-s-tr-4d/4126406

When trying to scrape the price, I run in to an issue. The price is wrapped in a section, and it is split up in a class=value and a class=label. I am interested in the value.

Currently, my code looks like this:

```py
url = 'https://www.bilbasen.dk/brugt/bil/audi/a4/20-tfsi-190-sport-s-tr-4d/4126406'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.103 Safari/537.36'}

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

car_price = soup.find(id = "bbVipPrice")
print(car_price)
```

But the result looks like this:

```
<section class="section" id="bbVipPrice">
<p id="bbVipPricePrice">
<span class="label">Pris</span>
<span class="value">409.000</span>
</p>
<p data-container="body" data-content="&lt;p&gt;Bilbasen kan som Danmarks førende brugtbils-site udregne markedets mest præcise gennemsnitspris. Dette gøres ved at sammenligne tilsvarende bilers årgang og pris, vægtet i forhold til kørte km.&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;Gennemsnittet på &lt;b&gt;kr. 410.000&lt;/b&gt; er udregnet udfra 7 &lt;b&gt;Audi A4 2,0 TFSi 190 Sport S-tr. 2017-2019&lt;/b&gt;, reg. &lt;b&gt;2018&lt;/b&gt; heraf 6 til salg og 1 solgt de sidste tre måneder og vægtet i forhold til kørte km.&lt;/p&gt;

&lt;p&gt;NB: Gennemsnitsprisen er vejledende. Forhold som stand og ekstraudstyr er ikke regnet med. Gennemsnittet er for forhandlerbiler.&lt;/p&gt;
" data-original-title="Vægtet Gennemsnitspris" data-toggle="popover" id="bbVipPriceAverage" onclick="BilBasen.Tracking.Analytics.trackEvent('vip', 'info average price');" rel="popover">
<span class="label labelStyleSmall bb-vip-average-price-label">gns.
                <span class="bb-vip-average-price">410.000</span>
<img class="bb-vip-popover-icon" src="/Public/images/ico-tooltip.png"/>
</span>
</p>
</section>
```

I would like to get the value inside: `<span class="value">409.000</span>` of 409.000. Can anyone help me adjust my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your last two lines to:

```
car_price = soup.find_all('span',class_='value')
print(car_price[0])
```

And your output is:

```
<span class="value">409.000</span>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot everyone. Just for clarification: when adding `.get_text()` to `car_price[0]` as `car_price[0].get_text()` i get the result as 409.000.

Answer (score 1):

```
car_price = [x.get_text() for x in soup.find_all('span', class_ = 'value')]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also regex the price out from a string

```
import requests
import re

r = requests.get('https://www.bilbasen.dk/brugt/bil/audi/a4/20-tfsi-190-sport-s-tr-4d/4126406', headers = {'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0'})
p = re.compile(r'"listingValue":"(\d+)"')
price = p.findall(r.text)[0]
print(price)
```

Without capturing group:

```
import requests
import re

r = requests.get('https://www.bilbasen.dk/brugt/bil/audi/a4/20-tfsi-190-sport-s-tr-4d/4126406', headers = {'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0'})
p = re.compile(r'(?<="listingValue":")(?:\d+)')
print(p.findall(r.text))
```

Answer (score 1):

The direct element present on the target your are trying to extract. You can use something like below,

```
car_price_chunk = soup.find('p',{'id':'bbVipPricePrice'})
```

The complete code look like,

```
url = 'https://www.bilbasen.dk/brugt/bil/audi/a4/20-tfsi-190-sport-s-tr-4d/4126406'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.103 Safari/537.36'}
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
car_price_chunk = soup.find('p',{'id':'bbVipPricePrice'})
if car_price_chunk:
    car_price = car_price_chunk.text.replace('Pris','').strip()
    print(car_price)
```

**Explanation**

Hope you require content from below chunk and if you check the target element present on 



 tag and whose identifier is **bbVipPricePrice**. for this you can use either select or find method.

```
<p id="bbVipPricePrice">
<span class="label">Pris</span>
<span class="value">409.000</span>
</p>
```

It will give you **409.000** as result